# How to create Geoocordinate predefined object in WP8?

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8

I'm going to use tests in my WP8 app. But now I meet the situation that I cannot create Geoocordinate with predefined latitude and longitude. Are there any standart way to handle this situation without creating wrapper that handle Geocoordinate object?

Answer (score 0):

new maps need GeoCoordinate instead of Geocoordinate so

```
 public static GeoCoordinate ConvertGeoCoOrdinate(Geocoordinate geoCooridinate)
        {
            return new GeoCoordinate(
                geoCooridinate.Latitude,
                geoCooridinate.Longitude,
                geoCooridinate.Altitude ?? double.NaN,
                geoCooridinate.Accuracy,
                geoCooridinate.AltitudeAccuracy ?? double.NaN,
                geoCooridinate.Speed ?? double.NaN,
                geoCooridinate.Heading ?? double.NaN);
        }
```

or you ca ndirectly initialize new GeoCordinate(latitude,longitude)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm just using data sent from Location service of device. I'm not using maps. I need to run my tests with fake data without manual click points in emulator.

Comment: @user1031381 so you want to add latitude, longitude manually?